# Occurring WordPress Multisite return 302 redirect status code

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, multisite, http-status-code-302

After Setup WordPress multisite (network setup), this is what happened.

**wp-config.php**

```
/* Multisite */
define( ‘WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE’, true );
define(‘MULTISITE’, true);
define(‘SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL’, false);
define(‘DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE’, ‘www.example.com’);
define(‘PATH_CURRENT_SITE’, ‘/’);
define(‘SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE’, 1);
define(‘BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE’, 1);
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wptmj/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ wptmj/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I checked the access log of my server then it shows

`“GET / HTTP/1.1” 302 – “-” “ELB-HealthChecker/2.0”`

How can I return this status code to 301?

Note: I already did basic troubleshooting for this kind of issue

I hope you can help me guys.
Thank you so much!

Comment: I don’t see how the rewriting in the .htaccess could cause this - the only external rewrite is the one for the admin area, all the rest are internal ones only. What is `ELB-HealthChecker/2.0`, is this some tool you are using to test your site - or is that some random bot that visited at some point?

Comment: @04FS I really don't know what is the cause of returning 302 status code, the .htaccess and wp-config.php it looks fine but when the multisite (subdirectory) setting up the status code change to 302 instead 301, and for the ``ELB-HealthChecker/2.0`` I'm currently using **AWS Elastic Load Balancing redirects traffic to healthy ** for my server.

Comment: Are you sure it’s not that load balancing to begin with, that might be responsible for that 302 redirect …?

Comment: I'm sure it's not the load balancing that causing the status code to change because even before I changed it to multisite, the load balancing was already there and status code was 301. Only when I changed it to multisite, it started to return the 302 status code.